# Updating multiple columns with data from subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, average

I am trying to update multiple columns in a row, with data from multiple columns in a subquery.

The following approaches did not work for me, and I can't find different ones that suit my needs:

```
UPDATE
    beers,
    (SELECT AVG(appearance) AS appearance, AVG(palate) AS palate, AVG(taste) AS taste, AVG(aroma) AS aroma, AVG(overall) AS overall, beer_id FROM reviews) AS review_total
SET
    beers.appearance = review_total.appearance, 
    beers.palate = review_total.palate, 
    beers.taste = review_total.taste, 
    beers.aroma = review_total.aroma, 
    beers.overall = review_total.overall
WHERE
    review_total.beer_id = beers.id
AND
    beers.id = 43
```

I don't get an error for this one, but 5 warnings and the row is not updated:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 5 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

Show warnings gives me:

```
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                            |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'appearance' at row 9991 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'palate' at row 9991     |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'taste' at row 9991      |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'aroma' at row 9991      |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'overall' at row 9991    |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I know this issue has to do with the data type, but the data type is float, i beleive thats what AVG's result is too:

```
mysql> describe beers;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(90)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| aroma       | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| appearance  | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| palate      | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| taste       | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| overall     | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The next query is slightly different:

```
UPDATE
    beers
SET
    beers.appearance = review_total.appearance, 
    beers.palate = review_total.palate, 
    beers.taste = review_total.taste, 
    beers.aroma = review_total.aroma, 
    beers.overall = review_total.overall
FROM
    INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(appearance) AS appearance, AVG(palate) AS palate, AVG(taste) AS taste, AVG(aroma) AS aroma, AVG(overall) AS overall, beer_id FROM reviews) review_total ON review_total.beer_id = beers.id
WHERE
    beers.id = 43
```

The error i got for this one is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(appearance) AS appearance, AVG(palate) AS palate, AV' at line 9
```

I really can't find a way to get this working and I hope someone sees what I'm doing wrong. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You use floating point numbers for rating beer? What are you drinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  UPDATE beers b
    JOIN 
       ( SELECT beer_id
              , AVG(appearance) appearance
              , AVG(palate) palate
              , AVG(taste) taste
              , AVG(aroma) aroma
              , AVG(overall) overall
              , beer_id 
           FROM reviews
          GROUP
             BY beer_id
       ) review_total 
      ON review_total.beer_id = b.id
     SET b.appearance = review_total.appearance
       , b.palate = review_total.palate
       , b.taste = review_total.taste
       , b.aroma = review_total.aroma
       , b.overall = review_total.overall
   WHERE b.id = 43;
```

or something like that

Comment: You deserve a beer! Thanks :)

Comment: OK, what's the result of "SELECT b.* FROM beers b JOIN reviews r ON r.beer_id = b.id ORDER BY overall DESC, taste DESC LIMIT 1;" ?

Comment: Westvleteren 12 (XII), with an ABV of 10.2%, this Trappist from Westvleteren, Belgium is in the highest overall rating selection and has the best rated taste among those. It is no secret that for true satisfaction one should drink this dark beer with its smooth caramel taste from a Trappist glass. And don't be too hasty, take small sips, and pour small amounts to enjoy the white foam for the full length of your drinking experience.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if there's one that's a little easier to get hold of?